# insert list of objects with linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a list of objects that I'm inserting in a database with linq-to-sql.
At the moment, I'm using a foreach loop that adds each element and that looks roughly like this:

```
foreach (o in List<MyObjectModel)
{
  using MyDataContext
  {
     TheLinqToSqlTableModel TheTable = new TheLinqToSqlTableModel();

     TheTable.Fieldname = o.Fieldname;
     .... repeat for each field

     MyDataContext.TheTablename.InsertOnSubmit(TheTable);
     MyDataContext.SubmitChanges();

  }
}
```

Is there a better way to insert a list of objects in a DB using linq-to-sql?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some quick improvements to consider..

a) Why creating datacontext for each iteration?

```
Using(Datacontext dc = new Datacontext())
{
    foreach(...)
    {

    }
   dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

b) Creating a stored procedure for the Insert and using it will be good for performance.

c) Using Transaction Scope to undo insertions if any error encountered.

```
Using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
   {
      dc.SubmitChanges();
   }
```

Comment: +1 Reusing the context here is a good idea. Using a stored procedure is an even better way to go. LINQ doesn't do bulk `INSERT`/`UPDATE` well as it really isn't intended to.

Comment: got it: no bulk operations in linq-to-sql; thanks for the tip on reusing the DC.

Comment: linq-to-sql will add a transaction itsself for each call to SubmitChanges so as long as you call it only once the transactionscope is useless. Also using an insert sp inside the foreach will not change it into a bulkinsert. In that case you need to move to SqlBulkCopy

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use InsertAllOnSubmit() method.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<Post> _post = getAllNewPost();

 Using(Datacontext dc = new Datacontext())
    {
        dc.Posts.InsertAllOnSubmit(_post);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
     }
```

That's all you need.

////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Object> Obj = (Enter the List you want to pass)

foreach (var item in Obj)
{
    item.Get your desired value after the dot
}
```